# Because Lisa had been a gymnast , she knew the importance of exercise. (still a gymnast?)

Tags: interpretation

> Because Lisa had been a gymnast, she knew the importance of exercise.

Q: Is Lisa still a gymnast now?

Answer (score 2):

**We don't know**. In all likelihood she isn't a gymnast now but it's not impossible.

Generally speaking grammar on its own can't tell you these things. You also need context.

Example

Two years ago, Lisa was a gymnast. Then she had a bad fall. The doctors told her she would have to retire from gymnastics but Lisa didn't give up. **Because Lisa had been a gymnast, she knew the importance of exercise**. She started a regime of very gentle exercise coupled with physiotherapy. Finally after two years of rebuilding her health, she is a gymnast once more!

Answer (score 0):

She is not a gymnast in the same way  that she was in the past (but she may still do some gymnastics)

The use of the past tense means that she isn't a gymnast now, however I understand, by "reading between the lines" that gymnast in this sentence means "elite gymnast".

I understand from the sentence that Lisa is *not now a gymnast in the same way that she was in the past*, but she may still do some gymnastics.

There is a fundamental ambiguity about being a "gymnast" which makes this example unclear.  That might not be the case for something for which there is a very clear definition.

Comment: *"She is not a gymnast in the same way that she was in the past"*  You are doing a lot of reading between the lines. Serena Williams has had injuries and come back from them. She also came back after becoming a mother. She is older now and so her tennis career is likely to decline but she was never stopped being elite because of breaks in her career.

Comment: I think your example of someone who had been a gymnast, stopped, and then started again is a very good one. This is one possible way to be "not the same".  You could say Serena Williams had been a tennis player before taking a career break.  But you wouldn't say "Coco Gauff had been a tennis player" as there is no discontinuty.  There is no career break. She "is a tennis player" or "has been..."

Comment: I don't think Coco Gauff would appreciate being called a "has been" ;-)   P.S. I know what you meant - only joking!